# CSS animation not working in Internet Explorer 10 and 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, css-animations, internet-explorer-11

The following css animation works perfect in Chrome, Mozilla, Opera browsers but doesn't work in Internet Exporer 10 and 11. What's wrong?

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/bm72w3n3/

```
.changed {
    -webkit-animation:target-fade 5s 1;
    -moz-animation:target-fade 5s 1;
    animation:target-fade 5s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes target-fade {
    0% { text-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow; }
    100% { -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear; }
}
@-moz-keyframes target-fade {
    0% { text-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow; }
    100% { -moz-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear; }
}
@keyframes target-fade {
    0% { text-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow; }
    100% { transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating an animation and inside that animation you try to animate using transitions. This might be supported in some browsers, but feels wrong anyway.

Declare a "real" animation like this:

```
@keyframes target-fade {
    0% { text-shadow: 0 0 10px red; }
    100% { text-shadow: none }
}
```

and it'll work on IE11 (haven't tried on IE10, but it should work).
We're basically telling the browser to set a red `text-shadow` for the first frame and to have no `text-shadow` for the last frame; it'll interpolate the other frames to make an animation.

In your original fiddle, you were setting a transition on the last keyframe to perform the actual animation, but IE doesn't support that.

I've updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bm72w3n3/1/) so you can see it live.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW (and not necessarily related to this particular question)

I had trouble getting animations started at all in IE 11, whether it was on page load or later. I was defining `animation-name` in the CSS and setting `animation-delay` and `animation-duration` from javascript (because it shouldn't start right away). But nothing happened when the event was triggered.

The solution was to reset the `animation-name` property from javascript when the animation should start. Somehow it probably wasn't able to completely load the keyframe definition at page load or whatever (even though I tried placing the keyframes at the top of CSS and also clearing the cache each time).

BTW I was trying to implement ["iOS Icon Jiggle"](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/creating_the_ios_icon_jiggle_wobble_effect_in_css.htm)